# keycloak startup taking very long time due to KC parsing through other schema tables

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Keycloak parsing through other schema tables (other than keycloak schema) and taking very long time to start, sometimes 1hour or more.
Is there anything wrong with keycloak configuration. I have configured only keycloak schema in standalone.xml file

After deleting tables from other schema and reducing from ~1,00,000 to 16000 tables, startup took approx 30 sec.

Keycloak version used : 3.4.3